# Splitviewcontroller xib after viewcontroller in xcode

Tags: xcode, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

i want to put splitviewcontroller xib after the viewcontroller xib in ipad version.i tried to search but it only shows to set splitviewcontroller xib from MainWindow..but i want to put normal view controller xib in starting and after that splitviewcontroller xib should be call.
any help will be appreciated
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i think u want present modal view controller for that.

as a new bee take a look at this to

http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-2-in-app-email-messageui/

u have to customize them as u needed